# EipAddress allocation in Alibaba Cloud VPC

Tags: alibaba-cloud

According to Alibaba Cloud EipAddress Allocation. 
An available EIP is randomly allocated in the specified region after this API is called. EIP supports ICMP, TCP, and UDP protocols, but does not support IGMP and SCTP protocols.

I create an EipAddress on Alibaba Cloud VPC using below mentioned Request code:

```
https://vpc.aliyuncs.com/?Action=AllocateEipAddress
&amp;amp;RegionId=cn-beijing
&amp;CommonParameters
```

How I can know which IP is assigned to my vpc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which IP address is created try this API call.

```
https://vpc.aliyuncs.com/?Action=DescribePublicIpAddress
&RegionId=cn-beijing
&<CommonParameters>
```

Here is sample response.

```
{
  “RequestId”:” 365F4154-92F6-4AE4-92F8-7FF34B540710”,
  “Code”:200,
  “Success”:”true/false”,
  “PublicIpAddress”:[
    “110.11.1.0/24”
  ],
  “RegionId”:”cn-beijing”,
  “PageNumber”:1,
  “PageSize”:100,
  “TotalCount”:1000
}
```

From documentation https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/65592.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.76.667b30a6zlzLJZ

Answer (score 0):

You can check which IP address is assigned by calling the following API Request:

**Request:**

```
https://vpc.aliyuncs.com/?Action=DescribePublicIpAddress
&RegionId=cn-beijing
```

Please replace your `RegionID` if you are using it in a different region.

The Action `DescribePublicIpAddress` is used to query the IP address range in a specified region.

**Response:**

```
{
  “RequestId”:” 123425345345252”,
  “Code”:200,
  “Success”:”true”,
  “PublicIpAddress”:[
    “111.10.1.0/24”
  ],
  “RegionId”:”cn-beijing”,
}
```